# How can I access the class attribute in STYLE tag of html from javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, stylesheet

I have CSS in Style tag on the html header. What I want is that thru javascript to access all the classes of Style tag and check whether it has `font-weight:bold` or not; at the end I want an array of classes with `font-weight:bold` so that I can assign id attribute to them in javascript later.

CSS

```
span {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}

.pt-Normal {
  line-height: 107.9%;
  margin-bottom: 8pt;
  font-family: Ca**strong text**libri;
  font-size: 20pt;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
}

.pt-DefaultParagraphFont-000000 {
  font-family: Calibri;
  font-size: 11pt;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.pt-DefaultParagraphFont-000001 {
  font-family: Calibri;
  font-size: 20pt;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.pt-Normal-000002 {
  line-height: 107.9%;
  margin-bottom: 8pt;
  font-family: Calibri;
  font-size: 11pt;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
}

.pt-DefaultParagraphFont-000003 {
  color: #FF0000;
  font-family: Calibri;
  font-size: 11pt;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

JAVASCRIPT from where I want to access the CSS class attribute.

```
//this is just example of one class having fontWeight:bold, but i want to do this in a generic way.

function sec(){var s = document.getElementsByClassName("pt-DefaultParagraphFont-000001");
        for (var z = 0; z <= s.length;z++){s[z].setAttribute("id",z.toString());}}
    var sc = document.getElementsByTagName("STYLE").style;
        if (sc.fontWeight == bold){
        //here i want to get all the class which have class attribute fontWeight:bold
        //later on i want to assign id attribute to those elements which have fontWeight:bold
    }
```

Comment: Instead of going through the style node, you may want to look at [`document.styleSheets`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/styleSheets) but you'll miss the browser's defaults like `<strong>` nodes, so maybe you'd still be better to simply loop through all elements and check their `getComputedStyle(el).fontWeight`...

Comment: the style description text is not a structured part of the DOM (it is also not XML!), but there is a CSSOM for that specific purpose. have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/styleSheets for more info! however if you are anything like me then you will probably not need it, but just change some styles with jQuery like $('my selector').css('my-attribute', 'myValue');

Comment: Why do you need access to the style sheet?

Comment: Can anyone pls provide js code no matter its `document.styleSheets` or `document.style`. @Kaiido @ZPiDER

Comment: @LGSon to assing id attribute to the class having fontWeight:bold

Comment: @Emma I feel you are taking the wrong route to solve your problem. You have explained what you want. But I think it will b better if you can take some time and update your question to say WHY you want this or what the problem is I am sure the community will have better ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method it will retrun an array `ok` contains elements who have `font-size: bold` then just get the className by `ok[index].className`
working example.

```js
var ok = $('[class]').filter(function() {
  return $(this).css('font-weight').toLowerCase().indexOf('bold') > -1;
});
var arrayBold = []
for(var i=0;i<ok.length;i++){
  arrayBold.push(ok[i].className);
}
console.log(arrayBold);
```

```html
<script src="http://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pt-Normal"></div>
<div class="pt-DefaultParagraphFont-000000"></div>
<div class="pt-DefaultParagraphFont-000001"></div>
<div class="pt-Normal-000002"></div>
<div class="pt-DefaultParagraphFont-000003"></div>
<style>
span {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}

.pt-Normal {
  line-height: 107.9%;
  margin-bottom: 8pt;
  font-family: Ca**strong text**libri;
  font-size: 20pt;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
}

.pt-DefaultParagraphFont-000000 {
  font-family: Calibri;
  font-size: 11pt;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.pt-DefaultParagraphFont-000001 {
  font-family: Calibri;
  font-size: 20pt;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.pt-Normal-000002 {
  line-height: 107.9%;
  margin-bottom: 8pt;
  font-family: Calibri;
  font-size: 11pt;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
}

.pt-DefaultParagraphFont-000003 {
  color: #FF0000;
  font-family: Calibri;
  font-size: 11pt;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
</style>
```

Comment: thanks for the solution, which finally works for me :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `document.styleSheets` to get the information you want. This is an array which contains all the style sheets of the document. Each style sheet again has the `cssRules` array. Each rule has the `cssText` property which caontains the information you want.

```
document.styleSheets.forEach(function(styleSheet){

    styleSheet.cssRules.forEach(function(cssStyleRule) {

         console.log(cssStyleRule.cssText);   //Add your condition here and build the array
    })


})
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that's also the best simple answer of this question. which i later understood. ;) @Charlie H

Answer (score 1):

I do not know if you are required to use Javascript but within jQuery this would be quite easy. Then you only need this:

```
$("*").each(function() {
    if ($(this).css("font-weight") == "bold") {
        $(this).attr("class", "bold");
    }
});
```

Which search through your CSS to find a DOM object that has your desired style: `font-weight: bold;` and for every object that it found an extra **CLASS*** is been added trough using the `.attr()` which makes your life much easier I guess. If you want to add an ID to each DOM object be careful that this ID should be an  unique. All this can be seen within this [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/zmfvhxmd/1/)

---

*I recommend to you that you should set a class due to the fact that an ID should be unique and therefore you need to generate multiple id's. Which make selecting all those id's more difficult. (thanks @Kaiido for the tip)*

---

In the end (in my created example) the output will be:

```
<body>
  <p class="class1 bold">
    SAMPLE TEXT 1
</p>
<p>
    SAMPLE TEXT 2
</p>
<p class="class2">
    SAMPLE TEXT 3
</p>
<p class="class3 bold">
    SAMPLE TEXT 4
</p>
</body>
```

Given this CSS:

```
.class1 {
    font-weight: bold;    
}

.class2 {
    font-weight: normal;    
}

.class3 {
    font-weight: bold;    
}
```

Comment: thanks @Rotan075 i got several solutions. your's one is also best in some situtaions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `cssRules` of `<style>` element `sheet` property, iterate `style` properties, values within a `for` loop; return `selectorText` of matched property, value

```js
var style = document.querySelector("style")
, rules = style.sheet.cssRules
, matches = []
, match = ["fontWeight", "bold"];
for (var i = 0; i < rules.length; i++) {
  if (rules[i].style[match[0]] === match[1]) {
    matches.push(rules[i].selectorText)
  }
}

console.log(matches)
```

```css
span {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}
.pt-Normal {
  line-height: 107.9%;
  margin-bottom: 8pt;
  font-family: font-size: 20pt;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
}
.pt-DefaultParagraphFont-000000 {
  font-family: Calibri;
  font-size: 11pt;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.pt-DefaultParagraphFont-000001 {
  font-family: Calibri;
  font-size: 20pt;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.pt-Normal-000002 {
  line-height: 107.9%;
  margin-bottom: 8pt;
  font-family: Calibri;
  font-size: 11pt;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
}
.pt-DefaultParagraphFont-000003 {
  color: #FF0000;
  font-family: Calibri;
  font-size: 11pt;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```